# Clojure standard metadata attributes

Tags: clojure, metadata, coding-style

Is there a "standard" list of metadata attributes (`:author`, `:copyright`, etc.) for Clojure, or do I need to read the source code :-)?

Perhaps [ClojureDocs](http://clojuredocs.org/) could take on this task (suggested).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no hard and fast rules that apply across the board - metadata is "context dependent" so can have different meanings depending on what kind of object you attach it to.

Note that the [Clojure website section on metadata](http://clojure.org/metadata) explicilty notes that metadata is for "arbitrary annotation of data".

Some comments:

- In certain parts of Clojure, metadata is meant to be used in a particular way. A good example is the metadata on vars described in Ralph's answer.
- If you define your own library with objects that have metadata, you can make the metadata mean anything you like.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to at least define some *conventions* for metadata? That way, tools could be written that look for and extract particular keywords.

Comment: Sure, but I think they would mostly have to be domain-specific conventions. Otherwise you run the risk that such tools might completely misinterpret something that means a different thing in different contexts....

Answer (score 2):

The best I've been able to find so far is http://clojure.org/special_forms.

Comment: +1 good list, although note that these only refer to metadata on vars.